# MFC MessageBox goes unresponsive

Tags: windows, mfc, messagebox

I have an MFC based application build using VS2017.

The application is designed to run a long running task and at the end of the task it opens an MessageBox with OK button.

If the message box is opened with then user is not actively connected to the vm(using rdp, say he is disconnected after launching the app) then the message box becomes unresponsive.

We need to kill the app from task manager to use the app again.

I tried to use Spy++ and noticed that that `WM_ACTIVATE` message is being processed by the MessageBox window when we try to activate the app.

But when I tried to click the message box no message is being received by the MessageBox window.

It appears as if the entire app is hung.

Is there any way i can troubleshoot the hanging app to check if there is any blocking code?

Comment: See [Is it legal to have a cross-process parent/child or owner/owned window relationship?](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20130412-00/?p=4683) and [Sharing an input queue takes what used to be asynchronous and makes it synchronous, like focus changes](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20130607-00/?p=4143). The short of it is: Launch the message box on the same thread that hosts the UI.

Comment: @Andrew Truckle So you run a task in ``InitInstance`` for a long time and at the end you show a dialog box? And this is on a VM? And it only happens within the VM, after a RDP disconnect?

Comment: I do t use VMs. Not sure why you tagged me in a comment really. The existing comment by someone else is good advice.